# SVN - How to upgrade SVN 1.7.1 to SVN 1.7.5

Tags: svn, upgrade

I have SVN version 1.7.1 in a Solaris version 10 server and Tortoise SVN 1.7.1 in the client.
I would like to upgrade the server to SVN 1.7.5 using a prepackaged binaries. The Release notes to upgrade an existing server installation say to just install the newest libraries and binaries on top of the older ones. I downloaded the binaries from CollabNet, however I don't know where in the Solaris 10 server the SVN libraries and binaries are?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [Collabnet documentation](http://www.collab.net/lightbox/download_info/1627/617):

> CollabNet Subversion installs into /opt/CollabNet_Subversion